# Highcharts not creating correct amount of labels (steps) in xAxis only first and last labels

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Here is a jsFiddle to my issue:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    
    xAxis: {
        categories: [full arrray in fiddle],
        labels: {
            step: 1
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: Array.from(Array(690).keys())
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qws90dux/

The chart seems to only take the first and last label, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this did not work is because of the amount of time needed to process each category which are long dates, this is basically what is written [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7706#issuecomment-359764605)
The solution was just to use `xAxis.tickInterval` instead, with the same interval as before.